# Is it possible to have non String type values in a Spring Environment PropertySource

Tags: spring, spring-el

I'm trying to add `ConfigSlurper`'s `ConfigObject`into an application context `Environment` in order to provide configuration values to the context.

The MapPropertySorce itself only expects its values to be of type `Object` only. But in the end property resolution fails as the `EnvironmentAccessor` will try to cast each `ConfigObject` to `String`.

So basically the question is, is there support for non String property resource values? Any supporting classes there (different EnvironmentAccessor?)

```
class ConfigSlurperLearningSpec extends Specification {
    def configurationResource = new ClassPathResource("/META-INF/de.troi/application.configuration")
    ConfigObject configuration = new ConfigSlurper().parse(configurationResource.getURL())

    def "use as application context property source"() {
        expect:
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context= new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()
        context.register(PropertySourceInjection)
        context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(new MapPropertySource("mapConfiguration", configuration))
        context.refresh()
        String configuredValue=context.getBean('testBean')
        configuredValue=='create'
    }
}

@Configuration
class PropertySourceInjection {
    @Value("#{environment['entityManagerFactory']['jpaPropertyMap']['hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto']}")
    Object hibernateHbm2ddlAuto;
    @Bean
    String testBean() {
        return new String(hibernateHbm2ddlAuto.toString())
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to inject non-string objects via ConfigSlurper.
Take a look at (shameless plug) https://github.com/ctzen/slurper-configuration

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow. Please indicate the solution to the question in your answer and then place the link in the question so that the user asking the question can follow up by following the if they want to.